# Spring Cloud Dataflow - "Waiting to get state machine" during stream deploy

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

In spring cloud dataflow during stream deploy the deploy fails with the error message

> "Waiting to get state machine"

Comment: Possible reason the Spring DSL is incorrect

Comment: This report is minimal and it doesn't include any details. Hard to reason through as to what would cause it. Perhaps include the versions, steps, and the entire stacktrace, we can review.

Comment: In my case it was due to incorrect DSL